heroku aplication getting error after launched
I'm new in deploying app. I started using Heroku.
I followed msome web tutorials, by heroku and another devs, everything goes ok but after i launhce the qpp and try to acces te link, i get this error in the heroku page:

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, > check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

I used the heroku cli to view the log with:
heroku logs --tail

And showed this:
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012844+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012844+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012844+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012845+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012845+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012845+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 32, in <module>
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012845+00:00 app[web.1]: db = SQLAlchemy(app)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012846+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012846+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 278, in __init__
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012846+00:00 app[web.1]: self.init_app(app)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012846+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 374, in init_app
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012847+00:00 app[web.1]: engines[key] = self._make_engine(key, options, app)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012847+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012848+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 665, in _make_engine
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012848+00:00 app[web.1]: return sa.engine_from_config(options, prefix="")
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012848+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012848+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 820, in engine_from_config
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012849+00:00 app[web.1]: return create_engine(url, **options)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012849+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012849+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012849+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012850+00:00 app[web.1]: return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012850+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012850+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 550, in create_engine
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012850+00:00 app[web.1]: entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012851+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012851+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 758, in _get_entrypoint
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012851+00:00 app[web.1]: cls = registry.load(name)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012851+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012851+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 374, in load
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012852+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012852+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres
2024-05-11T13:27:13.012944+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-05-11 13:27:13 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023692+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-05-11 13:27:13 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023694+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023694+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023695+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023695+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023696+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023696+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023696+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023696+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023696+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023697+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023697+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023697+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023697+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023697+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023697+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023698+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023698+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023698+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023698+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023698+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023699+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023699+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023699+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023700+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023700+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023700+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023700+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023701+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023701+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023701+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 32, in <module>
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023701+00:00 app[web.1]: db = SQLAlchemy(app)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023702+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023702+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 278, in __init__
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023702+00:00 app[web.1]: self.init_app(app)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023702+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 374, in init_app
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023702+00:00 app[web.1]: engines[key] = self._make_engine(key, options, app)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023703+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023703+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 665, in _make_engine
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023703+00:00 app[web.1]: return sa.engine_from_config(options, prefix="")
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023704+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023704+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 820, in engine_from_config
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023704+00:00 app[web.1]: return create_engine(url, **options)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023704+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023704+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023704+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023705+00:00 app[web.1]: return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023705+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023705+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 550, in create_engine
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023705+00:00 app[web.1]: entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023705+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023705+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 758, in _get_entrypoint
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023706+00:00 app[web.1]: cls = registry.load(name)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023706+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023706+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 374, in load
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023706+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023706+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres
2024-05-11T13:27:13.023843+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-05-11 13:27:13 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2024-05-11T13:27:13.087677+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-05-11 13:27:13 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:9) exited with code 3
2024-05-11T13:27:13.092721+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-05-11 13:27:13 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:10) was sent SIGTERM!
2024-05-11T13:27:13.193094+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-05-11 13:27:13 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
2024-05-11T13:27:13.193095+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-05-11 13:27:13 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2024-05-11T13:27:13.270023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2024-05-11T13:27:13.291929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2024-05-11T13:27:14.988365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aeesi-web-app-579745528501.herokuapp.com request_id=7b281039-d354-426c-b948-bd0ba268664e fwd="45.162.92.146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-05-11T13:27:21.908080+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aeesi-web-app-579745528501.herokuapp.com request_id=9bd5d4f9-56b0-4f8c-b939-2b2fe7830713 fwd="45.162.92.146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-05-11T13:27:24.057035+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aeesi-web-app-579745528501.herokuapp.com request_id=961f16d6-4c47-42de-bed2-0cecb16e40b1 fwd="45.162.92.146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https



My code:
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "wfefefhu" #Editar senha depois
folder = os.path.join(path, "database/files")

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = folder
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://sywbfrfepbxmmb:7c151d8ee719755d1d05c90e6e251fd952d1b536da569fb6d635a785261fe191@ec2-52-23-12-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d76n6ndo9mji2m'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

I read another posts and none of them helped me
But i don't know how to solve, anyone have some idea??

Read the linked duplicate. TL;DR: your database URL should start with postgresql://, not postgres://. But you've got another problem now: you've leaked your database credentials. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones immediately. Editing them out of your question is not enough.

Also, you should never hard-code your database credentials when using Heroku Postgres as they can change at any time. Always load them directly from the DATABASE_URL environment variable. It will be updated automatically when the credentials change.
